# Unable to get function to input data correctly from static webpage to Lambda funciton. Always returns Status code 300

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, amazon-web-services, api

I am trying to learn AWS and practice using a static website to query Cloudtrail data via a Lambda function. However whenever I input data from my website and from my GET API function and query it, it only returns status code 300(which is a failure alert).  I am not sure if it is something to do with my API gateway, my HTML/AJAX, or my Lambda function itself. I am using Python for my Lambda function with Boto3. Any advice or help be greatly appreciated as I am stuck. Thanks!

**AJAX Code**

```
<script>

         function retrieveFromAPI(){
         var param1 = $("#EventName").val()
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             data: param1,
             datatype: "json",
             url: "GET  API URL",
             success: function(data){
                 console.log("Got it", param1)
                 $("#lbl").html(data)
             },
             error: function(data){
                 alert("Unsuccessful Search....Try Again Please.  " + param1  +(" was not found") + JSON.stringify(data.responseText));
             }
                });
        };

    </script>
```

**HTML Form**

```
<form id="retrieve-form" method="GET"> 
        <h2>Select a Service to Query From</h2>
        <label for="CloudTrail">CloudTrail Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="EventName" placeholder="Enter Cloudtrail Name" name="EventName">
    <button id="submit" type="button" Onclick="retrieveFromAPI(event)" value="submit">Submit</button>
    <label id="lbl"></label>
</form>
```

**Lambda Function**

````
import boto3

client = boto3.client('cloudtrail')

#If the event name is in the list then return event name, or return nothing
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    if 'EventName' in event :
        EventName = event['EventName']
        response = client.lookup_events(
        LookupAttributes=[
            {
                'AttributeKey': 'EventName',
                'AttributeValue': EventName,
            },
        ]
    )
    else :
        EventName = '*';
    
    response = client.lookup_events(
        LookupAttributes=[
            {
                'AttributeKey': 'EventName',
                'AttributeValue': EventName,
            },
        ]
    )
#If the length of the response is greater than zero, it will make a list of the events
    if len(response['Events']) > 0 :
        events = []
        for event in response['Events']:
            CloudTrailEvent = json.loads(event['CloudTrailEvent']);
            events.append({ "awsRegion" : CloudTrailEvent['awsRegion'] , "EventId" : event['EventId'], "EventName" : event['EventName'] , "EventTime" : str(event['EventTime']), "requestID" : CloudTrailEvent['requestID']})
            
        return  {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'headers': {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' 
                 },  
            'body':  events
        }
    else :
        return {
           'statusCode': 300,
           'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' 
         },  
            'body' :  'No record found.',
    }
```s
````

Comment: it looks like it's successfully calling your function but you are returning 300 if there are no events found.  Can you add some debugging to see what event name is being passed and if the event name is valid and returns results? Add some logging to your lambda and look at the lambda's log in cloudwatch to better debug.

Comment: @JDD Do you have any useful information on how to go about that?

Comment: You really should return 404 for Not Found. Also you can test your code locally or in the AWS Lambda console.